# How to convert an Array to an Object.?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

How can I convert this array to this object?

```
const arr = [
  'key_1', 'text_key_1',
  'key_2', 'text_key_2',
  'key_3', 'text_key_3',
  'key_4', 'text_key_4',
]
```

```
const object = {
  key_1: 'text_key_1',
  key_2: 'text_key_2',
  key_3: 'text_key_3',
  key_4: 'text_key_4',
}
```

> I'm trying with Reduce but without success

Comment: You should add what did you try to do

Comment: Use a simple for loop with `i += 2` and add value at `i` as key and value at `i+1` index as value in every iteration

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const arr = [
  'key_1', 'text_key_1',
  'key_2', 'text_key_2',
  'key_3', 'text_key_3',
  'key_4', 'text_key_4',
];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(function * (in_arr) {
  const arr = [...in_arr]; // shallow copy
  while (arr.length) {
    yield arr.splice(0, 2);
  }
}(arr));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What are the benefits of using a generator here?

Comment: @A1exandrBelan benefits? I didn't realise the question asked for benefits :p nah, just looks cool :p

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder). Basically any even rest is a key and any odd rest is a value.

```js
const arr = [
  'key_1', 'text_key_1',
  'key_2', 'text_key_2',
  'key_3', 'text_key_3',
  'key_4', 'text_key_4',
]

function arrToObj (arr) {
  let lastKey = ''
  return arr.reduce((agg, keyOrVal, idx) => {
    const isAKey = idx % 2 === 0
    if (isAKey) {
      lastKey = keyOrVal;
      return agg;
    }
    return {
      ...agg,
      [lastKey]: keyOrVal,
    };
  }, {});
}

console.log(
  arrToObj(arr)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using `forEach()` can do it(suppose the array length is even)

```js
const arr = [
  'key_1', 'text_key_1',
  'key_2', 'text_key_2',
  'key_3', 'text_key_3',
  'key_4', 'text_key_4',
]

let result = {} 
arr.forEach((e,i) =>{ if(i%2==0){ result[e] = arr[i+1];}})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15)** if you don't mind: ([()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash), [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk), [fromPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fromPairs))

```js
const arr = ['key_1', 'text_key_1','key_2', 'text_key_2','key_3', 'text_key_3','key_4', 'text_key_4'];

const obj = _(arr).chunk(2).fromPairs().value();

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```